# iPhone - Cover Flow

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, coverflow

I want to integrate the Cover Flow for the images display in my iPhone Application can anyone guide me how can i do this. I found lot of tutorials on Google but not a single one is helpful

Comment: **Which one you have tried?** There are number of demos available on net. Have you tried any ?

Comment: Check this link : https://www.google.co.in/search?q=coverflow+demo+iOS&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a I found so many demos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cover flow is a private apple api so you cannot use it.
There are, however, open source alternatives like [FlowCover](http://www.chaosinmotion.com/flowcover.html).

Comment: Thankx Heliem for your response. Please can u guide me . what if i use the code given in above tutorial , is after using this my APP get reject from Apple , because Cover flow is private API

Comment: Yes, but what Heliem has offered you is is *not* a private API, so go for it.